# non-english characters in file names don't show up in file search

Tags: dolphin, encoding, filename, baloo

After installing Kubuntu 15.10 non-English (i.e. Greek) file names are not shown in file search. 
Any ideas about this issue?

(A QT issue caused some trouble in Firefox under 15.04, if I recall this right)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Arch Linux but it might help you. This is an issue of correctly setting the locale.

First thing, you need to generate your locales. For this you must uncomment the corresponding lines for each needed locale in `/etc/locale.gen`. For example, for Greek and American English locales uncomment the lines:

```
el_GR.UTF-8 UTF-8
el_GR ISO-8859-7
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8  
en_US ISO-8859-1
```

you now need to generate the locale:

```
# locale-gen
```

set your language in `/etc/locale.conf` (for example for US English)

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

and logout/reboot

Comment: Thanks for the tip, VIctor, I will try your tip on Kubuntu 15.10.

Comment: I did follow your suggestions, but nothing changed: Baloo keeps finding content on some files, the names of which are illegible; as I presumed previously these filenames were in non english characters (i.e. in Greek).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use international character sets much but I do have some files with non-English character names from other testing, and I can find them in Dolphin 17.12.2 on KDE Frameworks 5.47.0.

`balooshow -x /path/to/file` will show what KDE's Baloo file indexer thinks is going on. I tried it with some Greek characters in the file name:

```
 % echo 'Another test of Baloo/Dolphin file name indexing' > γένεος_baloo_test.txt
 % balooshow -x γένεος_baloo_test.txt
621851134983427 64771 144786 /home/spage/γένεος_baloo_test.txt
        Line Count: 1

Internal Info
Terms: Mplain Mtext T5 T8 Ttext X20-1 another baloo dolphin file indexing name of test 
File Name Terms: Fbaloo Ftest Ftxt Fγενεος baloo test txt γενεος 
...
```

and I can find that file by Filename in Dolphin by entering two or more letters from the start of any of the file name terms, including γέ.

I couldn't find Kanji characters:

```
% balooshow -x 日本国_déjà_balootest.txt
566660805229827 64771 131936 /home/spage/日本国_déjà_balootest.txt
        Line Count: 1

Internal Info
Terms: Mplain Mtext T5 T8 Ttext X20-1 another file test 
File Name Terms: Fbalootest Fdeja Ftxt balootest deja txt
...
```

Note how the Kanji characters didn't appear in "File Name Terms." I think this is why find by Filename for "deja" or "déjà" finds this file, but searching for the Kanji characters is a bust.